# Negative translate in tailwind not working

Tags: tailwind-css

Having a button transform translate by 50% to left does not work in tailwind:

```
<div class="relative h-12 w-full bg-yellow-500">
  <button class="-translate-x-50 absolute bottom-1 left-1/2 transform bg-red-500">hi there</button>
</div>
```

You can find the playground here:
[https:/play.tailwindcss.com/9V5ZYDMnqh](https://https:/play.tailwindcss.com/9V5ZYDMnqh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the class `translate-x-50` which does not exist in the [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/translate). Instead, you should use `translate-x-2/4` or `translate-x-1/2` like this:

```
<div class="relative h-12 w-full bg-yellow-500">
  <button class="-translate-x-1/2 absolute bottom-1 left-1/2 transform bg-red-500">hi there</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use a [custom style](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles) like this:

```
<div class="relative h-12 w-full bg-yellow-500">
  <button class="translate-x-[-50%] absolute bottom-1 left-1/2 transform bg-red-500">hi there</button>
</div>
```

Comment: that works for me  But preferably I would like to use the one from tailwind, as they have one for that exact property.